# Excel VBA: Why can't I get a range from a worksheet I passed into a function?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to use a helper function to get a range to store it into a variant, but I'm running into some issues.

At first, I just simply tried the following:

```
Function GetRange(RangeLetter As String, Optional LastUniqueLine As Long = 1048576) As Varient
    Static LastUniqueLineStr As String
    If LastUniqueLineStr = "" Then
        LastUniqueLineStr = LastUniqueLine
    End If
    Set GetRange = Range(RangeLetter + "2:" + LastUniqueLineStr)
End Function
```

But that didn't seem to work.  `Range()` seemed to be out of scope here or something, so I figured I had to pass in the worksheet to get it working:

```
Function GetRange(RangeLetter As String, Optional LastUniqueLine As Long = 1048576, Optional ActiveSheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Static LastUniqueLineStr As String
    Static CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    'If CurrentSheet = Nothing Then
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
    'End If
    If LastUniqueLineStr = "" Then
        LastUniqueLineStr = LastUniqueLine
    End If
    Set GetRange = CurrentSheet.Range(RangeLetter + "2:" + LastUniqueLineStr) ' This is the line where I get the error.
End Function
```

And that's not working either.  I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object 'Worksheet' failed
```

How do I get the range I want out of this when I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
GetRange = Range(RangeLetter + "2:" + RangeLetter + LastUniqueLineStr).Value
```

You were missing a `RangeLetter` which was resulting in a malformed address.  Also, use the `.Value` property to return a variant/array, and omit the `Set` keyword.

I continue to get the error when qualifying as `CurrentSheet.Range...` there is no `ActiveSheet` within the context of the Function, so you could pass a worksheet as a variable:

```
Sub Test()
Dim var As Variant
var = GetRange(ActiveSheet, "A")
End Sub

Function GetRange(sh As Worksheet, RangeLetter As String, Optional LastUniqueLine As Long = 1048576, Optional ActiveSheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Static LastUniqueLineStr As String
    Dim myRange As Range

    If LastUniqueLineStr = "" Then
        LastUniqueLineStr = LastUniqueLine
    End If

    Set myRange = sh.Range(RangeLetter + "2:" + RangeLetter + LastUniqueLineStr)

    GetRange = myRange.Value ' This is the line where I get the error.
End Function
```

Comment: You figured out my issue! Thanks.  As to the second part, I was trying to pass in the currently active sheet, and set it to a static variable so I didn't have to pass it in again later, but I'm having issues with making that work properly since it seems that the static declaration doesn't set it to `Nothing` initially, although i just figured out that I can test for `Nothing` with `If CurrentSheet Is Nothing` that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the error is in the line where your setting Your "GetRange" variable. It looks like the result of .Range(RangeLetter + "2:" + Last....) would create a range with an address of "a2:#" which will fail. A range in that format needs to be "a2:e7" or similar. Your range reference has to be symmetrical.  "RC:RC", "R:R", or "C:C". Hope that helps.